# Which of these should I 6-star first?

Tags: summoners-war

I'm stuck at the first phase of Summoner's War, which is 6-staring a farmer.
I can't seem to pick one as the ones that could finish a dungeon are very slow and those who could finish faster dies too early. I need some help with picking the best farmer monster and runing it effectively. I would like one that can finish off a dungeon fast, preferably the Hydeni Ruin,Tamor Dessert and Faimon Volcano dungeons.

---

My monsters are :

- **Lapis**, Water Magic Knight
- **Ellin**, Water Amazon
- **Julie**, Water Pierret
- **Lumirecia**, Water Sylph
- **Susano**, Water Ninja
- **Vigor**, Water Werewolf
- **Kernodon**, Water Lizardman
- **Sath**, Fire Grim Reaper
- **Raoq**, Fire Inugami
- **Tantra**, Fire Yeti
- **Garoche**, Fire Werewolf
- **Ramagos**, Wind Warbear
- **Yen**, Wind Rakshasa
- **Barque**, Wind Pirate Captain
- **Copper**, Wind Living Armor
- **Jojo**, Fire Joker

---

Sorry for the really long list, I've included ones that I've seen people using and some that people say would be a good farmer. If possible can you guys name at least top 5? And I also need the runes for the monster as well. Any suggestions?

Edit: I just got a fire joker

Comment: It all really depends on which stages for each level you want to farm. Seeing as Hydeni Ruins have a mix of elemental enemies, where as Tamor Dessert only has Fire and Wind. Then Faimon which has dark, and I believe fire. I always thought of Ramagos as a good character for bosses or arena defense. Raoq can easily clear stages if runed correctly. Lapis can be a good farmer from what I've seen as well. I will definitely 6* my Vigor and Raoq as soon as I can. Get yourself a Konamiya (water garuda) the support stats with it come in very handy! Teamed with Raoq and Ramagos would be awesome.

Comment: Do you have Lumi (water sylphID) or Tyron (water sylph)? because at the moment you are confusing 2 very similar monsters with each other.

Comment: I have a Lumirecia . I've seen her do really well on Tamor Dessert (3) albeit a bit slower than others. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With decent runes, Susano can become an amazing Faimon farmer. I would go down this route because the energy return on this scenario is a lot better than say, Tamor Desert North(3)

My Baretta can farm Tamor Desert North (Hell) if you're on Global, feel free to add me (efcseany21)

Lapis is good with Revenge runes for the newer Necropolis Dungeon, however - with this being your first 6*, I can't really imagine you trying to progress within this update. While Sath is a good choice with his two AoE attacks, also for Faimon Hell (1). Vigor is also a good unit but requires 6* energy runes (spd/hp%/hp%) with his Shred and Predator's Cry skill maxed out to be effective.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
I've actually gone to other forums for help and they've said Lapis would be the easiest to 6*, she only needs at least 4* Vamp/Rev with SPD substats. As long as she gets to go first on the boss stage, she's gonna survive. I've been using her for Faimon Hard (1) and she only dies at boss stage every few rounds, given I only have one fodder with me.

Although, she's kinda slow (she's not maxed yet). So I'm considering on getting another 6* farmer :C . So, any suggestion runes for Susano? I only know he needs Vamp runes and I've got 5* and 4* runes.

Comment: You could try running Susano with Vampire/Blade with Atk%/CD%/Atk%.

Comment: @Elite If this helped, please mark the given answer as accepted. This will help future viewers :)

Answer (score 1):

I understand this question is very old, but I'd like to add an extra perspective on what to 6* first in Summoner's War.

Almost any 6* can solo hell stages in the first four regions of the game, at a minimum, but a farmer designed to farm somewhere like Faimon hell is going to be relative trash if he has poor runes.

At this point, with the new tutorials on advancement, just giving Lapis the vampire/revenge quest reward set is enough for her to farm Faimon hell at max 5* (after you +12 the even runes and +9 the rest).

Either way, your initial focus should be your giants team, as Giants B10 will make or break your progression. This team will get you the runes you need to make a faster farmer. Any unit that either needs a lot of different stats to bring out their best (such as Belladeon) or is designed to be a major damage dealer (such as Sigmarus/Veromos, if fused) are good choices, but opt for survivability first and extra damage later for faster clears.

Once you are clearing Giants B10 in about 2:30 per run or faster, you'll be getting the runes you need to build a dedicated farmer for speed farming XP.